# Portable Class Library doesn't know ArrayList, StackTrace, etc

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I'm hoping I just missed something in the README somewhere, but...

I have a library of VB.net code that I'm trying to package into a PCL, ultimately for use under Xamarin. The code is relatively straightforward, there's a lot of File I/O using streams and some SQL client code, and a smaller amount of UI and control related code.

So I made a new PCL project, but I was confused what to select, so I chose Windows Store and .Net 4.5. I then Add...ed the source files from an existing project. Now I'm getting errors on the most basic things - ArrayList does not appear to exist in spite of importing System.Collections, and StackTrace doesn't exist in Diagnostics. Even simple things like StringFormat and SortedDictionary aren't there.

Did I skip a step somewhere? Perhaps I didn't download the right libs from MS? Or maybe I have to manually include a Reference to something? Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use generic collections.

Comment: `ArrayList` is obsolete. Stop using it.

Comment: "Portable" means that you must write code that can run both in a Store app and a desktop app.  When you look at the MSDN documentation for StackTrace or ArrayList then you'll see that those classes are not available in a Store project.  So they are not portable.  You can't use them.

Comment: I can ditch StackTrace, but I use ArrayList for COM/DLL compatibility. Is there a replacement? Generic collections do not work.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz So include the code that you've tried to build that is failing, with the signature that you're calling against